# if $f(n+1)-f(n)=P(n)$, exist a polynomial $Q(x)$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ : $Q(n)=f(n)$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math

> Let $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ such that, exist a polynomial
>   $P(x)$:
>
> $$f(n+1)-f(n)=P(n)$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$
>
> Prove that exist a polynomial $Q(x)$ such that for all $n \in
> > \mathbb{Z}$ :
>
> $$Q(n)=f(n)$$
>
> VietNam Math Olympic for college student.

It's my solution, may be not true?

We alaway show that exist $S(x)$ such that $P(x)=S(x+1)-S(x)$ and we have:

$S(n+1)-f(n+1)=S(n)-f(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

and thus, $S(n)-f(n)=const$ and $f(n)=S(n)+const??$

Comment: If you already have shown that $S(x)$ is a polynomial, then yes, that is enough, since then $S(x)+\mathrm{const}$ is also a polynomial.

Comment: but how to show that $S(x)$ is a polynonial ?

Comment: It was unclear by your language if you were saying you had already proved $S(X)$ was a polynomial or not. @RoadHuman

Comment: Are you familiar with the _binomial basis_ for the space of polynomials?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Binomial_coefficients_as_a_basis_for_the_space_of_polynomials

Comment: I am not convinced with my answer , so I want to verify that statement really true ? If not exits polynomial $S(x)$ then i fail :( @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Well, your answer is definitely incomplete, since you haven't proven that $S(x)$ exists, but it is the right direction to go in - it can be proven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will show that $S(x)$ exists for a single polynomial of degree $d$ for each $d$.

Let $P_d(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-(d-1))$. So $P_0(x)=1$, $P_{d+1}(x)=(x-d)P_d(x)$.

Then $P_d(x)$ is of degree $d$. Show that $P_{d+1}(x+1)-P_{d+1}(x)=(d+1)P_d(x)$.

Thus, letting $S_d(x)=\frac{1}{d+1}P_{d+1}(x)$ we get that $S_d(x+1)-S_d(x)=P_d(x)$.

Now, since the $P_d$ are polynomials of degree $d$, we can write any polynomial $P$ as a sum:

$$P(x)=\sum_{d=0}^D a_dP_d(x)$$

For some real values of $a_d$. Then define:

$$S(x)=\sum_{d=0}^{D} \frac{a_d}{d+1}P_{d+1}(x)$$

And show $S(x+1)-S(x)=P(x)$.

Comment: The comment from Steven refers to another set of polynomials, related, $Q_d(x)=\frac{P_d(x)}{d!}=\binom{x}{d}$. This has the property that $Q_{d+1}(x+1)-Q_{d+1}(x)=Q_{d}(x)$.